# Prove that the set $D=\{ku_n, n\in\Bbb N, k\in\Bbb Z\}$ is dense in $\Bbb R$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $ (u_n) $ be a real sequence, positive and converging to $ 0$.

Prove that the set $$D=\{ku_n, n\in\Bbb N, k\in \Bbb Z\}$$
is dense in $\Bbb R$.

I have to show that between any two reals $ x $ and $ y $, there is an element of the form $ku_n $.
I did it when $xy<0$, using the convergence to zero.
But if $ xy\ge 0$, i couldn't.
Any idea or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Small hint: You don’t need $\lim u_n=0,$ just $\liminf u_n=0.$

Comment: You don’t need any kind of convergence to $0$ when $xy<0,$ since $k=0\in\mathbb Z.$ I’ll elaborate my other comment when you provide more work.

Comment: Use the characterization of density by sequences: 
$$A \text{ is dens in } \mathbb{R} \iff \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists (x_n) \in A^{\mathbb{N}}, x_n \to x$$

Comment: @Essaidi But how will you construct the sequence.

Comment: Think about the floor function. Hint :\\
1) When $|x|$ is big enough $\lfloor x \rfloor \approx x$.\\
2) $\dfrac{x}{u_n} \to \infty$.

Comment: It's a nice exercise. It allowed us to solve complex problems about density such as :
$$A = \{\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{m} / n, m \in \mathbb{N}\}$$ $$B = \{\ln{n} - \ln{m} / n, m \in \mathbb{N}^*\}$$  and $$C = \{m + n \sqrt{2} / m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ are denses in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We have :

1. $\left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{u_n} \right\rfloor u_n \to x$.
2. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{u_n} \right\rfloor u_n \in D$.

Then $D$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suffices to consider $x>0$ and show that within any $\varepsilon>0$ neighborhood of $x$ there is an element of set $\{ku_n:k\in\mathbb{Z},\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Let $n_0$ large enough so that $0<u_{n_0}<\varepsilon$. Let $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ be such that $k\leq\frac{x}{u_{n_0}}<k+1$.
Then $ku_{n_0}\leq x<(k+1)u_{n_0}$ and
$|x-ku_{n_0}|<u_{n_0}<\varepsilon$